# What is an Anglepoise lamp called in America?

Tags: nouns, american-english

What word do Americans use to refer an Anglepoise lamp?

[image: an Anglepoise lamp]

Comment: Yeah, that would be a [swing arm desk lamp](http://www.walmart.com/c/kp/swing-arm-desk-lamps) to most in the US.

Comment: Unless genericisation has occurred, this is like asking 'What do Americans call a Bremont watch?'

Comment: "Scotch tape" in America is "Cellotape" in Britain. Just because it's a brand-name, it doesn't mean it's universal across the Atlantic.

Answer (score 3):

We always called it a "drafting lamp" - but that was in art school, so I don't know how widespread it is. (US)

Answer (score 2):

[Anglepoise](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/anglepoise) lamp is the term used also in AmE given its specific and unique features:

> - The [Anglepoise lamp](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglepoise_lamp) is a balanced-arm lamp designed in 1932 by British designer George Carwardine.
> - A type of desk lamp with a jointed arm and counterbalancing springs that hold it in any position to which it is adjusted:
>     : an anglepoise lamp

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Anglepoise%20lamp&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CAnglepoise%20lamp%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Banglepoise%20lamp%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAnglepoise%20lamp%3B%2Cc0) : Anglepoise lamp in AmE.

> - A key feature of the Anglepoise design and patent is the placement of all springs (either three or four) near the base. The design was extensively copied by other companies, usually in simplified form, and is still in use. Some derivatives use a heavy balance weight instead of the springs. The most common version replaces the arm linkages with two independent paralleogram linkages, with a pair of light tension springs on each half of the arm.

also generally referred to as  *a [balanced-arm](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced-arm_lamp) or  swing arm lamp*:

> - sometimes called a floating arm lamp, is a lamp with an adjustable folding arm which is constructed so that the force due to gravity is always counteracted by springs, regardless of the position of the arms of the lamp.

(from Wikipedia)

Comment: I am interested in the fact that both you and the OP spell the word with a capital A. Was Anglepoise at one point a brand name?

Comment: @WS2 -      It is a trademark. When used to indicate that specific lamp it is usually spelled with capital A : http://twelvetwentyseven.wordpress.com/history/. When used to indicate a generic 'swing arm' lamp it is spelled without  capital A.

Comment: Go into a store in the US and ask for an Anglepoise lamp.  Be prepared for some dumb looks.

Comment: @Josh61 Whoever thought of it did well, it's a good name; very descriptive of what it is. And they are excellent to work with.

Comment: Especially if its [eight feet tall](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41mVDDHUdHL._AC_SX110_SY165_QL70_.jpg)

Comment: +1 for *swingarm lamp*; I don't think *Anglepoise* would be understood in North America outside of design enthusiasts and professionals who work at drafting tables, though the lamp type itself is fairly common.

Comment: If you're in the US and you go to buy a "swing arm" lamp, you will most likely be shown the wall-mount lamps like they have over hotel beds.

Comment: That's why you say swing arm **desk** lamp.